# Uninitialized Local Variable 'totalPrice' used

Tags: c++, class

I am creating code for a class that puts books into a shopping cart, however, the code has to be included in classes. It is going pretty good, except for my totalPrice double. I have listed it in my public Class, but it isn't recognizing it. What did I do wrong? Do I have to initialize it somewhere else? Thanks a ton for helping me.

```
class ShoppingCart
{
    private:
        Book* bookArray[100];
            int arrayEnd;

    public:
        void addBook(Book *);
        double totalPrice();

        ShoppingCart();

};

ShoppingCart::ShoppingCart() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        bookArray[i] = { NULL };
    }
    arrayEnd = 0;
}

void ShoppingCart::addBook(Book *currentItem) {
    bookArray[arrayEnd] = currentItem;
    arrayEnd++;
}

double ShoppingCart::totalPrice() {
    double totalPrice;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (bookArray[i] != NULL) {
            totalPrice += bookArray[i]->getPrice();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return totalPrice;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what "isn't recognizing it" means (in an edit to the question).

Comment: you need to initialize totalPrice to 0. you are trying to  sum uninitialized variable

Comment: The variable `totalPrice` in `totalPrice()` method is uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's declared, but it's not initialized, try changing it to

```
double ShoppingCart::totalPrice() {
double totalPrice = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
...
```

When you declare a variable, it has a value in it that just happens to be what was at that memory location when it's created (it's basically useless). The compiler throws a warning when you use that variables value because it doesn't think you want to use it. If you overwrite that useless value with 0, you can use that variable for summation.

Comment: You're not adding something to nothing, and the compiler is throwing a warning, not an error.  If you fail to initialize it, it retains whatever (essentially random) value it had when that memory was allocated to that variable.

Comment: Right, I probably shouldn't have given an explanation that simple. Thanks guys

Comment: You learn something new every day I guess. Both me and the asker.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize totalPrice to 0. you are trying to sum uninitialized variable. here is the fix.

```
double totalPrice = 0;
```